# Date Field is not updated properly. Date filed updated with 12:00:00AM instead of original Value

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, oracle10g, oracle9i

I have a Stored Procedure with 'Date' as an argument.

The Procedure is called from a function which in turn is called from a Java code.

I pass the `Date` from the Java code as a parameter.

Now the problem is that the Stored Procedure does not update the proper time in the DB's 'Date' column.

The `Date` gets updated properly but the time is updated with the default value `12:00:00AM`, instead of the original value.

I use `DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE` method to call Stored Procedure from function.

**JAVA CODE:**

```
 
    import java.sql.CallableStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;

    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.Transaction;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

    public class StackOvFlow {

    /**
    * 
    * @param args
    */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String status = "";
    try {
    System.out.println("IN MAIN");

    int userId = 1360822386;
    StringBuffer batchUpdateSQL = new StringBuffer("BEGIN ");
    StringBuffer updateSQLnew = null;
    String date = "30-JUL-2012 10:30:00";

    String currDate = "to_date(" + "'" + date + "'"
    + ",'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')";

    updateSQLnew = new StringBuffer(
    "BEGIN PKG_AMB_LOGIN.P_TRACK_USER("
    + userId
    + ",'" 
    + currDate
    + ""
    + ");Exception When BufferMgr.app_errors_exit Then Rollback; Return; End; ");

    batchUpdateSQL.append(updateSQLnew);

    batchUpdateSQL
    .append(" Exception When BufferMgr.app_errors_exit Then Rollback; Return; End;");

    System.out.println("INPUT ::::");

    System.out.println(batchUpdateSQL);

    String res = getMonthlySave(batchUpdateSQL.toString());
    System.out.println("Response: " + res);

    } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception" + e);
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(status);

    }

    public static String getMonthlySave(String plSqlBlk) {

    String output = "";
    System.out.println("IN GET MONTHLY SAVE");

    Session session = null;

    CallableStatement cstmt = null;

    ResultSet rs = null;

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure(
    "hibernate.cfg.xml")

    .buildSessionFactory();

    session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

    try {

    System.out

    .println("*calling SP **");

    cstmt = session.connection().prepareCall(

    "{? = call PKG_THR.P_UPDT(?,?)}");

    cstmt.setFetchSize(10000);

    cstmt.registerOutParameter(1,

    oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        cstmt.setInt(2,186);

    cstmt.setString(3, plSqlBlk);
    cstmt.execute();

    rs = (ResultSet) cstmt.getObject(1);
    int size = rs.getFetchSize();

    System.out.println("The size of fetch is " + size);

    while (rs.next()) {

    output = output + rs.getString(1);

    }
    System.out.println("OUTPUT ::::::::::::");

    System.out.println(output);

    } catch (Exception e) {

    System.out

    .println("Exception occured in executing query  in fetchdetails....... ");

    e.printStackTrace();

    }

    finally {

    transaction.commit();

    session.close();

    }
    return output;
    }

    }
```

**PL/SQL Function:**

```
    CREATE or REPLACE
    PACKAGE BODY PKG_THR AS
    FUNCTION  P_UPDT(login_id number,plsql_block varchar2) RETURN cursor_type IS
    louvtBuff a_XMLBUFFER_TABLE;
    loutRowBuff a_XMLBUFFER_TABLE := a_XMLBUFFER_TABLE();
    EXIT_MESSAGE EXCEPTION;
    lreturn number;
    offset BINARY_INTEGER := 1;
    kount BINARY_INTEGER := 5;
    ln_dbms_cur NUMBER;
    ln_cur_execute NUMBER;
    j number := 1;
    i number;

    buffout cursor_type;
    BEGIN
     BufferMgrXML.CLEARBUFFER;
     BEGIN
     pkg_glbl.g_login_id  := login_id;
     pkg_glbl.g_connect:='1';

     ln_dbms_cur := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;

     DBMS_SQL.PARSE(ln_dbms_cur,plsql_block,DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);

     ln_cur_execute := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(ln_dbms_cur);

     EXCEPTION
     WHEN BufferMgr.app_errors_exit then
           lreturn := BufferMgrXML.getXML(louvtBuff,1,1);
           RAISE EXIT_MESSAGE;
     END;
```

Comment: Please post some code - from your description, it doesn't sound like the date is being passed correctly, and oracle is defaulting to midnight because the format of your input is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

Because there is not much code to observe, it is hard to tell what is wrong in exactly this case.

Quite typical reason is usage of [java.sql.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html), which sets all time fields to 0. If that is the case, you can use [java.sql.Timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) instead (fractions of seconds will be lost).

Comment: i have posted the code. Any help would be really appreciated.